# SQL Server 2016 count similar rows as a column without duplicating query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that returns data similar to this pseudo-table:

```
| Name | Id1 | Id2 | Guid |
|------+-----+-----+------|
| Joe  | 1   | 1   | 1123 |
| Joe  | 2   | 1   | 1123 |
| Joe  | 3   | 1   | 1120 |
| Jeff | 1   | 1   | 1123 |
| Moe  | 3   | 42  | 1120 |
```

I would like to display an additional column on the output, listing the total number of records that have matching GUIDs to a given row, like this:

```
| Name | Id1 | Id2 | Guid | # Matching |
+------+-----+-----+------+------------+
| Joe  | 1   | 1   | 1123 | 3          |
| Joe  | 2   | 1   | 1123 | 3          |
| Joe  | 3   | 1   | 1120 | 2          |
| Jeff | 1   | 1   | 1123 | 3          |
| Moe  | 3   | 42  | 1120 | 2          |
```

I was able to accomplish this by joining the query with itself, and doing a count. However, the query is rather large and takes awhile to complete, is there any way I can accomplish this without joining the query with itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a window function:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by guid) as num_matching
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Elegant, Gordon.